Rename property using Ajv custom keyword
Is it possible to write a custom AJV keyword that renames a property in an object?
For example, this schema:
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "foo": { "type": "string" },
        "bar": { 
            "type": "number",
            "inputName": "inputFoo"
        }
    }
}

The following object should properly be validated:
{
    "foo": "string",
    "inputName": 123
}

and it should be transformed to the following:
{
    "foo": "string",
    "bar": 123
}

Is this possible and if so, how?

Why not correct your schema? Or correct your data before validating? What does that mean, "write a custom AJV keyword"?

I can not change the schema because the input data is predefined and I want to transform it using the schema. By "custom AJV keyword" I meant user defined keywords: https://ajv.js.org/keywords.html

You can define a custom Ajv keyword to rename a property in your object. You can read more about it in Ajv docs, but here's an example that should work for you:
ajv.addKeyword({
  keyword: "renameProperty",
  compile: (schema, parentSchema, it) => {
    const validate = (data, dataPath) => {
      // new property name
      const { renameTo } = schema;
      // parentDataProperty is the current property name (i.e. inputName)
      const { parentData, parentDataProperty } = dataPath;
      // mutate current object: replace existing property 
      parentData[renameTo] = parentData[parentDataProperty];
      delete parentData[parentDataProperty];
      return true;
    };
    return validate;
  }
});

const schema = {
  type: "object",
  required: ["foo", "inputName"],
  properties: {
    foo: { type: "string" },
    inputName: {
      type: "number",
      renameProperty: { renameTo: "bar" },
    },
  },
};

const obj = {
  foo: "string",
  inputName: 10,
};

const validate = ajv.compile(schema);
console.log("validate = ", validate(obj), obj);

// obj = { foo: 'string', bar: 10 }

